# Is it possible to invite friends without showing Facebook dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am building an iOS app that is using facebook to gain traction. I would like to invite some friends, that user selects from list, but without showing facebook confirmation dialog, i want that to happen behind the scenes.

Reading documentation there is property `frictionlessRequestsEnabled`, but even that shows dialog, where i have option to disable showing dialog in the future. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Well, hopefully not. How would you prevent malicious sites from inviting users' friends without them knowing?

Comment: This is for iOS app, which is much more personal

Comment: Still - it seems unlikely FB would allow such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

Many apps invite all of your friends without showing the Facebook Dialog Box. It is possible by modifying the FBSDK.  Simply clone the FBSDK repository to your local machine, edit in Xcode and Command+B to build the framework for your own use.  The following classes are relevant to inviting in the FBSDK for iOS:

FBSDKWebDialogView
FBSDKWebDialog
FBSDKGameRequestDialog

**To get the URL Generated for the dialog view:**

In FBSDKWebDialog.m in `-(BOOL)show`:

```
NSURL *URL = [self _generateURL:&error];
```

This is the URL generated to load the web view.  It is possible to use this URL without the web dialog view, as long as it is only generated once (access token gets reset every time the URL is generated) and is used on a mobile browser.

**To Invite Without The Dialog Box**

You can use javascript to simulate clicking the go button by doing something like this (assuming you have specified your parameters and  recipients properly and your app is already set up through Facebook)

In FBSDKWebDialogView.m in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{  NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById(\"u_0_0\").click();"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"u_0_0\").click();"]; }] selector:@selector(main) userInfo:nil repeats:NO ];
```

As long as the webView is present somewhere, you may be able to do these actions with little interference for the user.  You could set the webView frame to be very small, or potentially hide the view altogether.

Facebook is however, policing hard against this sort of thing and it likely that that there will be more protection against this in the future.

FBSDK Repo Here:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12921820)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Am new to SO. Have modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for ages.